# posting of json data to express app is getting { }

Tags: jquery, json, node.js, express

In the following nodejs server I tried to get the posted json data. But the server does not getting the json data what i sent.

The followng code is nodejs app

```
var express    = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body) // populated!
res.send(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

And Iam sendign the json data from the follong page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/', 
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    data: JSON.stringify({number:1}),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But the server giving the result only the empty data for each request like the following.

```
{}
{}
{}
```

Am I missed any thing here. Please suggest me on this.

Comment: Have you tried sending the data without the `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: i don't see your home route. Is it available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you should use `app.post()`:

```
app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body) // populated!
    res.send(req.body);
});
```